# Building a Budget Deep Learning Machine

Tags: processor, performance

So I want to create a fast Deep Learning Machine with Nvidia's RTX 2060 but I'm divided between AMD's Ryzen 2600X and Intel's Intel Core i5-9600K. Now I know that there is a big gap in the price, but I wanted to know a few more opinions because I saw what Lambda Lab offers and I got cold feet just before I placed my last two orders(CPU and MOBO).

I mainly want to use it for Image Recognition with Neural Networks, I don't want to do NLP (at least for now). So I believe here that performance is key.

Now, in case you ask, here is the build I was going for (without the case):

1. CPU: AMD ​Ryzen 5 2600X Box
2. SSD: Samsung 970 Evo Plus 250GB
3. GPU: Gigabyte GeForce RTX 2060 6GB Mini ITX OC
4. RAM: Corsair Vengeance LPX 8GB DDR4-3000MHz
5. PSU: Seasonic M12II-620 Evo
6. MOBO: Asrock B450 Pro4

So, what do you think? Should I go for Intel or AMD for Deep Learning?

P.S because I'm new to Pc Building, feel free to point out whether or not this is a post for the Data Science subdomain, of Stackexchange, or not.

Comment: I'm not a Deep learning specialist, I don't know what you are looking for in a processor in your case, but here is a side by side comparison: https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i5-9600K-vs-AMD-Ryzen-5-2600X/4031vs3956